# Unexpected behaviour while outputting file in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

for x in range(10, 11): 
    df.to_csv("file_%x.csv" % x, index=False)
```

Instead of returning `file_10.csv`, the code returns `file_a.csv`. Why is this happening? I checked the value of `x` in the loop and it is indeed 10, so why is it being converted to 'a'?

Comment: use this `"file_{0}.csv".format(x)` instead of this `"file_%x.csv" % x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old `%`-style [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) uses largely C-derived directives. `%x` instructs the formatter to print the number in hexadecimal, so 10 *is* `a`. Use `%s` to stringify in the default way.

```
df.to_csv("file_%s.csv" % x, index=False)
```

or, better, use f-strings if you're on Python 3.6+ (which you should be)

```
df.to_csv(f"file_{x}.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: I thought f-strings were introduced in 3.6; am I remembering that wrong?

Comment: Nope, mistake was on my end. Thanks, @JackTaylor

Answer (score 2):

`%x` converts the value to hexadecimal. What you want is `%d`.

```
>>> for i in range(16):
...     print("%d %x" % (i, i))
...
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
10 a
11 b
12 c
13 d
14 e
15 f
```